# How to make multiple top app bars for different screens

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I'm working with pure kotlin, jetpack compose, and destinations library by raamcosta.

I have multiple designs for the top app bar and depending on the screen I'll show a different one or no top app bar at all. Also, the title of the top app bar might be something like a product number or an order number so the title is not a static string.

I have the following code to determine if I should show the app bar or not:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun TopAppBar(navController: NavController) {
    val currentDestination =
        navController.appCurrentDestinationAsState().value ?: NavGraphs.app.startAppDestination
    var shouldShowAppBar by rememberSaveable { (mutableStateOf(true)) }

    shouldShowAppBar = when (currentDestination) {
        LoginOtpScreenDestination -> false
        LoginPhoneScreenDestination -> false
        OnboardingScreenDestination -> false
        SignupPhoneScreenDestination -> false
        SignupOtpScreenDestination -> false
        else -> true
    }

    AnimatedVisibility(
        visible = shouldShowAppBar,
        enter = slideInVertically(initialOffsetY = { it }),
        exit = slideOutVertically(targetOffsetY = { it })
    ) {
         // calling TopAppBarDesign function here
    }
}
```

what should I do next? how can I call one top app bar in the scaffold in the MainActivity and make it change dynamically?